# Dealing with list.index(x) error in Python 3

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

How do I deal with Index errors of a list in *Python*?

If it is a string, I can do the following:

```
if text.find("blah")!=-1:
```

I know why `!=-1` cannot be used in lists, but how do you get a block of code to be executed only if `list.index(x)` does not return an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `in` operator, like this

```
if "blah" in text:
```

It will evaluate to be Truthy, if `"blah"` occurs anywhere in `text`.

Similarly, you can use the same `in` operator with list objects, like this

```
if key in list_object:
```

**Note:** In case of lists, you need to use `list.index` to get the actual index of the element. It doesn't return `-1`, but throws `ValueError`, if the search value is not found in the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
try:
    lst.index(10)
    #Do something
    #executes if it doesnot throws any error.
except ValueError:
    print "something"
    #if list.index returns an error
```

Try except is a very elegant of way of restricting your program from dying when an error is executed.

Comment: True but this would be perfect I you wrote the exact exception tht would be raised

Comment: Should really be only catching the `ValueError` here: `except ValueError:`. It is bad practice to catch all possible exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments.